# shell script to accept multiple sets of arrays in for loop

Tags: bash, shell, variables, for-loop

Hi can some one help me here on a shell script?

I have 2 hosts and 4 servers, I want to pass using for loop

```
host1 -->  host1_server1 host1_server2 
host2 -->  host2_server1 host2_server2
```

I want to use a `for` loop to print both sets, outputting both sets:

set 1 output

```
hostname : host1 servers: host1_server1
hostname : host1 servers: host1_server2
```

set 2 output

```
hostname : host2 servers: host2_server1
hostname : host2 servers: host2_server2
```

How can I achieve this using a Bash shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Bash solution is to use Bash arrays, [Indirect References](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html), and `printf`.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a hosts=(host1 host2)     # array of variable names; quoting not needed

declare -a host1=("host1_server1" "host1_server2")
declare -a host2=("as-host2_server1" "as-host2_server2")

for Host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
   Indirect="$Host[@]"
   printf "hostname : $Host servers: %s\n" "${!Indirect}"
done
```

The above generates the following output:

```
hostname : host1 servers: host1_server1
hostname : host1 servers: host1_server2
hostname : host2 servers: as-host2_server1
hostname : host2 servers: as-host2_server2
```

This solution also takes advantage of the `printf` command's behavior to reuse the format to consume all of the arguments.  From `man bash`, see the `printf` section:

> The format is reused as necessary to consume all of the arguments

As a point of interest, note that the Bash idiom `"${Variable[@]}"`preserves any spaces within array elements. Also, if there are no elements in the array, this idiom expands to nothing. This in many circumstances is very useful.

These approaches, combined, allow for a single for loop to accomplish what you are asking for.

Comment: And, if you want a further generalization, you can define an array `declare -a hosts=(host1 host2)` and then change the loop to `for Host in "${hosts[@]}"; do`

Comment: hi Steve thanks for your Quick help, its working fine but when i give on host1 as as-host1, as-host2 getting syntax error its not accepting ' - ' in name  syntax error near unexpected token `('      `declare -a as-host1 =(as-host1_server1)'

Comment: All that is needed is to quote the hosts.  I've updated the Bash script above.

Comment: If this solution answers your question, please click the check to mark it the accepted answer. This will help the community and reward me for this effort!

Comment: Steve thanks for your quick help its fixed my issue ,:)